# Editing text in a wx.textcontrol with wx validator

Tags: python, wxpython

I have a validator which Ive attached to a wx.TextCtrl inside a wx.Dialog:

```
myinput = wx.TextCtrl(self, validator=MyValidator())
```

All that validator does is it binds a wx.EVT_CHAR event and checks whether the input is a number and whether the number of characters entered is less than 5.

The problem is when I select the text with my mouse i.e. turn it to blue I cant replace the text if the number of characters is already at its maximum.

How can I detect whether the user has selected the text of that specific text box and has pressed a key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at how the IntValidator inside the file wx\lib\intctrl.py is created.
Now use the intctrl instead of creating your own and limit the characters entered to 4 by using the method SetMaxLength(4)